# C# Project Standard Directory Layout

Tags: c#

The java build tool "maven" has a [standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for projects.  What is the equivalent type of directory layout for a C# project?  I'm just learning C# and .NET and it seems that the IDE just dumps everything into one directory, heh.  Does C#/.NET follow a convention for the directory structure?

EDIT:  This would be for a desktop application (windows forms or wpf).  I'm looking at one of these two, but I don't know enough yet to really know which one.  Ultimately I would like to learn both.

Comment: Probably it would be interesting whether you refer to a Class Library, a Website Project, a Web Application Project, a Windows Forms Project, a WPF solution or even something else.

Comment: Which IDE are you using? Visual Studio definitely does *not* dump everything into one directory.

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 ultimate. The `*.cs, *.xsc, *.xsd, *.xss, *.sdf, *.resx` files are all in the project directory at the same level. That is every file I have created for this "mini" sample projects from "Head First C#" (where I'm learning C#). I created a new class and it just put it in the same directory as everything else. It looked like chaos, so I looked for some "standards", didn't find anything and decided to ask the experts here.

Answer (score 2):

In C# directory layout should be strictly related to the namespaces you have. Each directory creates subnamespace. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229026.aspx) you may find instructions how to name namespaces properly.

If you use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), it will inform you if your directory (namespace) layout is OK. The main rule is that there shouldn't be namespaces with a few classes/interfaces (FxCop suggests merging two namespaces into one in such a situation).

I think that's all I can say without knowing of some special project type (Uwe mentioned some of them in his comment) you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get the following structure in your project :

- /bin/Debug (after a DEBUG build)
- /bin/Release (after a Release build)
- /obj/Debug
- /obj/Release
- /Properties (contains AssemblyInfo.cs + Resource files when added via the assembly's properties)
- /ServiceReferences (contains service references if any are present in your assembly)
- In addition to the above, any solution folders you create (via r-click solution explorer -> add new / folder) will be present in your project's folder.

Does this help?

Comment: Is the properties folder the location where you would store other configuration information for your project?  Where would you store your embedded database?

Comment: .config files usually end up in the root of your assembly - it is important to remember that the config file needs to be present in your project's output directory, so if you have and satellite projects with their individual configurations you'll most likely have to merge those with your main config file and it should work, As far as embedded databases go, in case of ASP.NET projects I think they end up in a folder named App_Data